# Compare output values of a java program with existing values in textfiles in specific column , replace values

Tags: java, text-files

Compare the values of the output of a program with existing values saved in a text file. 
e.g. output of the program version 01 is "Tomatoes", 40

Text file:

```
BufferedReader buffet = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sqlcalculation.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = buffet.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = buffet.readLine();
        String[] columns = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    buffet.close();
}
```

(name)          (number)    (version)

This returns :

```
Vegetables      33      01
Fruits          28      02
Meat            50      03
```

So, what I need is to extract the value for [NUMBER] , in the case that [VERSION]=01.  Any ideas how to do this?

I compare this value with the new program output, consequently I want to conditionally replace the old value for number and name with the new value for number and name.

For col 3=01, I want to replace [vegetables] and [33] with [tomatoes] and [40] (the new program output)

```
  if (version==01) {
   //   numnber=.... (THIS I WANT from READING/UPDATING THE TEXT FILE !)   
        number=40;  //this I want automatically  
    } else if (version==02) {
        ;
        //number=... 
        number=53;
    } else {
        System.out.println("something went wrong");;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `version`? If it's string then you need to use `equals()`

Comment: it is an integer, but converted to a string in the read process. Yes, that is true but that's not the problem.  The problem is that I don't find a suitable method  to find from the text file the value of number for version=1 or version equals "1".  So, something as if version(column03)=01 (or equals), than extract (and conditionally replace) value of column01 (string name) and column2 (integer number).

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat everything as strings since you have a String array, `columns`, you are working with. Change your while loop as below

```
while (line != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = buffet.readLine();
    String[] columns = line.split(" ");
    switch (columns[2]) {
        case "01":
           columns[0] = "tomatos";
           columns[1] = "40";
           break;
       case "02":
           columns[0] = "Something";
           columns[1] = "53";
       //case "03" ... and so on for rest of versions
       default:
           //Unknown version. add some error handling
           break;
    }
    // do something with columns[]
}
```